# How to check if Product is already in Cart and NOT duplicate it when clicking on Add to Cart (JavaScript localStorage Cart)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm playing around with this JavaScript cart that is pretty nifty:
https://github.com/gabrieleromanato/jQuery-sessionStorage-shopping-cart

It works well except I don't know how to prevent product duplicates when adding to cart.

I am a novice at JS so what is obvious to others won't be to me.

I'm not sure where to make the modification exactly, below are some suspected areas to look at:

```
// Adds items to the shopping cart
handleAddToCartForm: function() {
    var self = this;
    self.$formAddToCart.each(function() {
        var $form = $( this );
        var $product = $form.parent();
        var price = self._convertString( $product.data( "price" ) );
        var name =  $product.data( "name" );
        var image =  $product.data( "image" );
        var url =  $product.data( "url" );

        $form.on( "submit", function() {
            var qty = self._convertString( $form.find( ".qty" ).val() );
            var subTotal = qty * price;
            var total = self._convertString( self.storage.getItem( self.total ) );
            var sTotal = total + subTotal;
            self.storage.setItem( self.total, sTotal );
            self._addToCart({
                product: name,
                image: image,
                url: url,
                price: price,
                qty: qty
            });
            var shipping = self._convertString( self.storage.getItem( self.shippingRates ) );
            var shippingRates = self._calculateShipping( qty );
            var totalShipping = shipping + shippingRates;

            self.storage.setItem( self.shippingRates, totalShipping );
        });
    });
},

/* Add an object to the cart as a JSON string
 * @param values Object the object to be added to the cart
 * @returns void
 */

_addToCart: function( values ) {
    var cart = this.storage.getItem( this.cartName );

    var cartObject = this._toJSONObject( cart );
    var cartCopy = cartObject;
    var items = cartCopy.items;
    items.push( values );

    this.storage.setItem( this.cartName, this._toJSONString( cartCopy ) );
},
```

I have modified the original code to include a product image and URL, however that is it.

I don't understand sessions and objects well, so hoping to learn a little around this if anyone is able to help out.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: What does the cart HTML look like when there is an item in it? Does the item row has some sort of attribute related to the product?

Comment: Wait, so you don't want me to buy two of the same item at once? I have to check out, go back, and check out again? Seems like a bad user experience. You probably want to modify _addToCart, I'm not entirely sure of how everything is structured so I'm not sure how you need to check... What does console.log(items) give you?

Comment: why not loop through 'items' in add to cart and see if the product name is there?

Comment: @Craig Each item HTML is output like so

    <tr>
    <td class="name"><p>ITEM NAME A</p></td>
    </tr>

Comment: @Gerrit0 It's not being used for shopping purposes, no quantity or price is used.  Just items, selected or not.

Comment: @Vinny That sounds good, how would that be done?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll want to add something like:
(assuming the cart class its "cart", change this otherwise)

```
if($('.cart td.name p').indexOf(name) == -1) {
    // Item not already in the cart
}
```

Probably put that in the $form.on('submit') around everything, if thats where the code actually adds it to the cart. You probably want to tell the customer why they cant add that again.

A better solution would probably be to check items in the cart upon page load and hide/disable the "add to cart" button for existing items.

EG:

```
function checkCartItems(){
    $('.cart td.name p').each(function(){
        var itemName = $(this).text();
        $('[data-name="'+itemName+'"]').addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    });
}
checkCartItems();
```

and then add the "checkCartItems()" to end of the addToCart function to re-check after an item is added.